# How do I install shared data on Windows with CPack?

Tags: windows, cmake, wix

I'm trying to install some data which would be shared between a few different programs we make. The signs seem to point to C:\ProgramData\${CompanyName}, which is fine, but of course CPack objects to absolute paths.

In this case, I'm targeting the WIX installer.

I can't seem to find any documentation which says what I ought to be using.

`INSTALL (FILES ../config/netstat_protocol.xml DESTINATION ${INSTALL_OCU_DIR} )`

If I want INSTALL_OCU_DIR to resolve to something like C:\ProgramData\MyCompanyName\ocu, what's the right way?

---

Here are the lines I last tried:

`set(INSTALL_OCU_DIR "%PROGRAMDATA%/CyPhy/ocu")
INSTALL(DIRECTORY DESTINATION ${INSTALL_OCU_DIR} DIRECTORY_PERMISSIONS WORLD_READ WORLD_WRITE WORLD_EXECUTE)
INSTALL (FILES ../config/netstat_protocol.xml DESTINATION ${INSTALL_OCU_DIR} )`

This results in the error: Executing op:

```
SetTargetFolder(Folder=C:\Program Files\cyocu 2.0.0\%PROGRAMDATA%\CyPhy\ocu\)
```

Comment: is `%APPDATA%\MyCompany` not suitable?

Comment: Are you trying to replicate the "INSTALL ..." command through wix? Are you trying to make a wix installer that runs another program to actually install the files to %programdata% ?

Comment: I want to avoid any end runs around either cmake or wix. I'm aiming for nice concise cmake commands with platform differences handled as much by cmake as possible.

Comment: Well, using %PROGRAMDATA% made the complaints go away. I haven't tested the installation yet, go some other stuff to work through.

Comment: Searching suggests the proper keyword is CommonAppDataFolder.

Comment: Using %PROGRAMDATA% in the CMakeLists.txt propagates them unchanged to the msi, terminally confusing the installer.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I'm having the same problem and documentation is really hard to find.

Comment: In the end, the solution I chose was to rethink how we were handling shared data on all the platforms, and pull it back into a directory with the executables and libraries. It's easier to manage the packaging, and and the results, and easier for support, since customers don't have to go trawling around in a system directory for files.